# How upload file PDF in Laravel Using Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I wanna get file pdf document from View use Vue to Laravel. But it still bug. Can help me what is wrong with my code?

This is my Blade

```
<template>
    <form class="form" files="true" method="post" @submit.prevent="onSubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>File SK
                <input type="file" multiple class="form-control-file" name="fileSk" id="fileSk" ref="fileSk"
                       @change="fileSkUpload()"/>
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

This is my Vue Code for getting file

```
fileSkUpload(event) {
    let files = event.target.files;
    if (files.length) this.fileSk = files[0];
},

onSubmit() {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('fileSk', this.fileSK);
    data.append('_method', 'put'); // add this

    axios.post('/psu/list/store', {
        data: this.data,
    }).then(response => {
        this.data = ''
    }).catch(error => {
        if (error.response.status === 422) {
            this.errors = error.response.data.errors || {};
        }
    });
},
```

This is my Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $dokumen = new Dokumen();
    $psu = new Psu();

    $fileSk = $request->file('fileSk');
    $data = $request->input('fileSk');
    $extension = $fileSk->getClientOriginalExtension();

    Storage::disk('uploads')->put($fileSk->getFileName() . '.' . $extension, File::get($file));

    $dokumen->file_image_dokumen = $fileSk->getFileName() . '.' . $extension;

    $dokumen->save();
}
```

I got this Error:

```
"Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null"
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi9cI.png)

Comment: Can you check the network tab in your browser and confirm if the file is getting attached to the request? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, i uploaded and still error @RossWilson

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you haven't initialised the `$file` variable.

Instead of using the `Storage` facade to store the file you can just use the `Request` itself:

```
$fileSk->storeAs('', $fileSk->getFileName() . '.' . $extension, 'uploads');
```

[Storing uploaded files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#storing-uploaded-files)

---

You seem to have a few of issues in your JS code.

**1.** Don't include the parentheses  in `@change="fileSkUpload()"` as this will cause the `event` not to be passed to the method:

```
@change="fileSkUpload"
```

alternatively you will have to pass the event yourself:

```
@change="fileSkUpload($event)"
```

[$event docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers)

**2.** I noticed that in your `fileSkUpload` method you're referencing `this.fileSk` but in your `onSubmit` method you're referencing `this.fileSK` (capitalised K) - these should be the same.

**3.** You don't need to wrap the `FormData` in a object. Change your axios call to just be:

```
axios.post('/psu/list/store', data)
    .then(response => {
    this.data = ''
}).catch(error => {
    if (error.response.status === 422) {
        this.errors = error.response.data.errors || {};
    }
});
```

Comment: I got Error "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null" @ross-wilson